# ios- Login and Signup Button Wont Work (treehouse and parse)

Tags: ios, authentication, parse-platform, segue

My login and signup buttons WERE working but for some reason after I fill out the unsername and password field - and press the login button - the botton wont push to my inbox controller.  But if i stop my project and then re run it, it will load as logged in.  I don't know why! Any help would be appreciated--

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
}


- (IBAction)login:(id)sender {


NSString *username = [self.usernameField.text
                      stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSString *password = [self.passwordField.text
                      stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

if ([username length] == 0 || [password length] == 0) {
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oops!"
                                                        message:@"Make sure you enter a username and password!"
                                                       delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Okey"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
} else {
    [PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:username password:password block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry!"
                                                                message:[error.userInfo objectForKey:@"error"]
                                                               delegate:Nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok"
                                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];
        } else {
            [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        }
    }];
}
}

@end
```

Comment: I would recommend using the method on https://parse.com/tutorials/login-and-signup-views because their delegate is very reliable and simple. You may need to restructure you view sequence, however.

Comment: Can you capture any logs / error messages returned from the server?

Comment: hey @dwightgunning i get this log :  Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UINavigationController: .  Other than that no errors or anything.

Comment: does it work if the only code in `login:` is `[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];`?